# django admin custom model admin url

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

So I have a `Bookings` model in my django app. I am using django admin to display information about the booking. I want to create a custom url directly from the `changelist` view -- (not the `change` view).

I want the url to be something like: `/admin/bookings/generate_bookings`.

I've registered that url in my model admin by overwriting the `get_urls` function. The issue is that django automatically resolves any url that follows the syntax of `model_name/<text>` as a detail view url and it assumes whatever is in `text` is a primary key of the given model.

As a result I get the error:

`booking object with primary key u'random_text' does not exist.`

Is there any way to get my custom url to resolve first?

Answer (score 1):

if you do:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(BookingAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        (r'^generate_bookings/$', self.your_custom_function)
    )
    return my_urls + urls
```

and in changelist template somewhere:

```
<a href="generate_bookings/">Generate Booking</a>
```

it should work. It always worked for me at least

Comment: It works fine on the `change` view. Not on the `changelist` view